# Are the exp and log maps of Riemannian geometry conformal

Tags: riemannian-geometry

For any Riemannian manifold are the exp and log maps (from a predetermined base) conformal? If not, are there some manifolds where they are and others where they aren't?

Comment: They are for Euclidean space, clearly. I think otherwise conformality is rare.

Comment: Have you checked whether this is true for the standard unit sphere?

Comment: The Taylor series expansion of the exponential map shows that, at the very least, the curvature has to vanish at the base point.

Comment: I have rolled back an edit which seemed needlessly pedantic

Comment: @Yemon Choi:A question is asked, not a topic is explained. The omitted ? makes a grammar mistake.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See Robert Bryant's answer to [Complex manifolds in which the exponential map is holomorphic](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/67903/complex-manifolds-in-which-the-exponential-map-is-holomorphic) in which he proves that the surfaces for which the exponential map is conformal are precisely the flat ones.

If the exponential map is conformal on some Riemannian manifold of dimension $\ge 3$, it is a conformal map on the intersection $P \cap B$ of any 2-plane $P\subset T_m M$ in any tangent space with the ball $B\subset T_m M$ of radius equal to the injectivity radius. So the curvature vanishes on $e^{P\cap B}$, i.e. the sectional curvature vanishes, so the Riemannian manifold is flat.